# Simplify $32^{1/3}-(2(0.25)^{1/3}-3(16)^{1/3}+5(0.5)^{1/3}-2(54)^{-1/3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to simplify the following expression:

$32^{1/3}-(2(0.25)^{1/3}-3(16)^{1/3}+5(0.5)^{1/3}-2(54)^{-1/3})$

The answer in my textbook is: $5(2^{1/3})-\frac{1}{6}(4)^{1/3}$. I can't simplify it to this form..

Comment: By $(0,25)$, $(0,5)$, do you mean $0.25$ and $0.5$?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of powers of two here:

$$2^{5/3}-(2^1\cdot 2^{-2/3}-3\cdot 2^{4/3}+5\cdot 2^{-1/3}-2^1\cdot 3^{-1}\cdot 2^{-1/3})$$
In the last term I observed $54=2\cdot 3^3$.
Group the twos, remove the parens:
$$2^{5/3}- 2^{1/3}+3\cdot 2^{4/3}-5\cdot 2^{-1/3}+ 3^{-1}\cdot 2^{2/3}$$
The powers of $2$ have different numerators now. However, you know that the integer part of the exponent can be factored out like this, $2^{5/3}=2^{1+2/3}=2\cdot 2^{2/3}$. You can use this to make most of the terms equal and group them together. Powers greater than 1 can be reduced down, and powers below zero can also be shifted the same way.
$$2\cdot 2^{2/3}- 2^{1/3}+6\cdot 2^{1/3}-(5/2)\cdot 2^{2/3}+ (1/3)\cdot 2^{2/3}$$
$$(2-5/2+1/3)\cdot 2^{2/3}+(6-1)\cdot 2^{1/3}$$
$$(-1/6)\cdot 2^{2/3}+5 \cdot 2^{1/3}$$

Comment: Good. I suggest that you add a `\cdot` between the $5$ and the $2$ in the final answer to make it foolproof.